# jQuery validator gives error when a form element contains id with some special symbols. 'Unrecognized expression'

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I have a form with some elements that use ids wich special symbols like this:

```
id="$FormData[1]$PersonData[1]$PhysicalPerson[1]$PersonName[1]$Affix[@type='qualification' and @position='prefix'][1]cb"
```

I have a `function getEscapedID(id)` that I use to escape a problematic characters when I need to find an element using jquery selector:
 `var input = $("#"+getEscapedID(id))`.

This is not a problem - when I try it, I get the exact needed  element. But calling `input.valid();` gives me an error:

Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: `label[for='$FormData[1]$PersonData[1]$PhysicalPerson[1]$PersonName[1]$Affix[@type='qualification' and @position='prefix'][1]cb']`

EDIT:
My question is whether it is possible to do something about it. If not, then I will consider simplifying ids.

Comment: Why do you have id's like that? That's just asking for trouble.

Comment: My question is whether it is possible to do something about it. I wasn't creating the form.

Comment: The form is pretty complicated. I think this is a good question, I don't understand the downvote. Do you think this is simply error to think out such id - that nobody should get into such trouble?

Comment: Ok, I created a simple form, but it works there. So the problem should be elsewhere. When I finish it completely, I will edit this question.

Comment: When you look at the error you might see that the "starting" single quote from `qualification` is already closing your initial `label[for='` string. Which seems to have been the problem here, but nevertheless changing the ids was a pretty good decision, imho. ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<s>The problem was that I used perhaps old jquery.validate.min.js script. When I tried the one from here, it works:
http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/jquery.validate.js</s>

Eventually the form's ids were changed because it was not valid according to http://validator.w3.org, so I doubt the problem was primarily in the plugin.

Comment: Moreover, I was told that the plugin was more up to date than the 1.9.